# Django - one to one relation, mostly NULLs at one end, NOT NULL on the other

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I’m writing simple application with Django and PostgreSQL for managing a home book library, where I can have many borrower profiles for people who borrowed books (`Borrower` model). And I have users, who can borrow a book themselves, so that the book becomes borrowed by the user’s borrower profile.

On the other hand admin can lend books to any borrower, even to one unregistered as a user.

So I have a few `MyUser`s (and that field, btw, references Django’s `User`) and many `Borrower`s, and I want to create a one-to-one relation between them, but every `MyUser` *has* to reference one unique `Borrower`, but many `Borrower`s will not reference any existing `MyUser`s (they can only reference one or none, or in another words, be referenced by only one or no user).

My question is: how to model that optimally? Using `models.OneToOneField`, `models.ForeignKey` and which model should reference which?

I will probably have many borrowers, who do not have user accounts.

Natural solution seems to be `OneToOneField(Borrower, null=False)` in a `User` model. But then when searching for users based on borrowers I will have to mostly deal with `DoesNotExists` exceptions and only once in a while I will get a proper result.

I can also make `ForeignKey(Borrower, unique=True, null=False)` – then I will have to check sets having single element or empty.

And I can make `ForeignKey`s both ways:

```
class Borrower(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, unique=True, null=True)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    # ...
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(Borrower, unique=True, null=False)
```

That implicitly defines the relations and I can easily make searches both ways, but it also makes one additional, redundant field in database tables.

I will probably just stick with `OneToOneField` for now, but I’d like to know which approach makes most sense in this case. What are the proc and cons? And is there an alternative, better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the `OneToOneField`; as you say, it is the most natural solution.

The only downside you mentioned is that `borrower.user` can raise a `DoesNotExist` exception. If you don't like that, you can always define your own method (or property) to return something else (like `None`) instead. Something like:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    borrower = models.OneToOneField(Borrower, null=False)

class Borrower(models.Model):
    @property
    def user(self):
        try:
            return self.myuser
        except DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @user.setter
    def user(self, user):
        self.myuser = user
```